# ViewPager is not populate with images from url in Android

Tags: android, json, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-pageradapter

I am using view pager in my app to images from json data. The json data is coming from rest api. I have deserialize data in controller class. I am using Picasso imgae loader to load the image from json. Now the problem is after running the app, no image is showing on viewpager. I am not finding the reason why it is showing blank.

```
My Controller class

    public class NewsController {
    private static final String TAG = NewsController.class.getSimpleName();
    private UserCallbackListener mListener;
    private NewsRestApiManager mApiManager;
    private AppImage appImages;

    public NewsController(UserCallbackListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
        mApiManager = new NewsRestApiManager();
    }

    public void startFetching(){

        mApiManager.getNewsApi().getNews(new Callback<String>() {

            @Override
            public void success(String s, Response response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "JSON :: " + s);

                try {
                    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(s);

                    for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);

                        NewsModel news = new NewsModel();
                        news.setTitle( jsonObject.optString( "title") );
                        news.setBody( jsonObject.optString( "body" ) );
                        news.setUpdatedAt( jsonObject.getString( "updated_at" ) );

                        ArrayList<AppImage> list = new ArrayList();
                        JSONArray imageArray =jsonObject.getJSONArray("appImages");
                        if (imageArray.length() > 1) {
                            for(int j=0; j<imageArray.length();j++){
                                appImages  = new AppImage();
                                try {
                                    appImages.setSrc( new JSONArray( s ).getJSONObject( i ).getJSONArray( "appImages" ).getJSONObject( j ).optString( "src" ) );
                                }catch (JSONException e){
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                list.add(appImages);

                            }

                        }
                        news.setAppImages( list );

                        TeaserImageSmall coverImage=new TeaserImageSmall();
                        coverImage.setSrc( new JSONArray( s ).getJSONObject( i ).getJSONObject( "teaserImageSmall" ).optString( "src" ));
                        news.setTeaserImageSmall(coverImage);
                        mListener.onFetchProgressNews(news);


                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    mListener.onFetchFailed();
                }

                mListener.onFetchComplete();
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error :: " + error.getMessage());
                mListener.onFetchComplete();
            }
        });

    }
    public interface UserCallbackListener{
        void onFetchStart();
        void onFetchProgressNews(NewsModel news);
        void onFetchProgressNews(List<NewsModel> userList);
        void onFetchComplete();
        void onFetchFailed();
    }
}
```

ViewPager Adapter

```
private List<NewsModel> imageList; 
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private Context context;

public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context, List<NewsModel> imageList ) {
    this.context = context;
    this.imageList=imageList;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return imageList.size();

}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view==object;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup view, int position) {
    layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
    View itemView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.sliding_img_layout, view, false);
    final NewsModel imageFromNews=imageList.get( position );
    ImageView myImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.sliding_image);


    Picasso.with(itemView.getContext()).load(imageFromNews.getTeaserImageSmall().getSrc()).into( myImage );
    view.addView(itemView, 0);

    myImage.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i=new Intent(context,DetailNews.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            i.putExtra("src",imageFromNews.getTeaserImageSmall().getSrc());
            i.putExtra("title",imageFromNews.getTitle());
            i.putExtra("body",imageFromNews.getBody());
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
    } );
    return itemView;
}


@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView((View) object);
}
```

My Main Fragment is

```
public class OptionMenuFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{


private static ViewPager viewPager;
private static int currentPage = 0;
private List<NewsModel> imageList=new ArrayList<>( );
private ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
private NewsController mController;


public OptionMenuFragment() {

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.option_main_fragment, container, false);

    viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    adapter=new ViewPagerAdapter( this.getActivity(),imageList );
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    CircleIndicator indicator = (CircleIndicator) view.findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    indicator.setViewPager(viewPager);
    mController = new NewsController(this);
    mController.startFetching();

    // Auto start of viewpager
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final Runnable Update = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (currentPage == imageList.size()) {
                currentPage = 0;
            }
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage++, true);
            System.out.println(viewPager.getCurrentItem());
        }
    };

    Timer swipeTimer = new Timer();
    swipeTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(Update);
        }
    },2000,5000);

 }
@Override
public void onFetchStart() {

}

@Override
public void onFetchProgressNews(NewsModel news) {
    System.out.println(news.getTeaserImageSmall());
    imageList.add(news);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public void onFetchProgressNews(List<NewsModel> userList) {

}

@Override
public void onFetchComplete() {

}

@Override
public void onFetchFailed() {

}
```

My laoyut for View pagers is

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1.1">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

    <me.relex.circleindicator.CircleIndicator
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Add a log statement into `onFetchProgressNews`. Does it run, or not?

Comment: @cricket_007 I can see the image now. But circular indicator is gone. I have modified my question

Comment: Your viewpager is match parent height... Where would the indicator be displayed?

Comment: You can download the sample code and run it. https://github.com/ongakuer/CircleIndicator/blob/master/sample/src/main/res/layout/fragment_sample_loop_viewpager.xml

Comment: Yes I already use this cicular indicator. I change viewpager heigh to wrap content. still it is showing nothing

Comment: That link uses a FrameLayout, not a RelativeLayout, by the way

Comment: now I change to frame layout. still same

Comment: Again, I might suggest downloading that whole sample app separately from your existing code and seeing how it works